# Delphi XE4 FireMonkey IOS Mobile Application – Crypto libraries

Tags: ios, delphi, cryptography, firemonkey-fm2, delphi-xe4

Are there any Crypto libraries that will work the following Delphi Profiles?

1)  Delphi – windows

2)  Delphi – ios

3)  Delphi – mac

I need functions like SHA1, SHA256, MD5, DES,  AES

Comment: @David = yes there is no crypto libraries for Delphi-ios

Comment: "Shopping list" questions ("Please post a list of links for me") are not appropriate here. There are Meta posts [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/172661) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661) that explain the reasons. Voting to close as "not constructive". Good luck.

Comment: As Ken said, we don't answer "Shopping List" questions, but maybe you have a look at your "Shipping List" from Delphi (INDY)

Comment: @CharlesFaiga: OpenSSL can be used on Delphi iOS, but you have to compile/obtain the files manually. [Marco Cantu blogged about it](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/using_ssl_delphi_ios.html).

Comment: try LockBox3 and Spring4Delphi in PurePAscal mode
Maybe they'd compile and pass the tests, dunno

Comment: @Arioch - the ios compilers  is  different from the Delphi desktop compiler.  Seven of the older string types are not supported on iOS:
AnsiString,WideString,AnsiChar and PAnsiChar, PWideChar, OpenString, ShortString +  iOS are 0-based instead of 1-based. LOCKBOX will need a major upgrade to work on delphi-ios

Comment: @CharlesFaiga 1-based mode should be able to be engaged by pragma, but about RawByteString you're correct. Well, i made unofficial x64 asm for s4d crypto, and for what i remember there always were PaurePascal implementations (or at least i made them before re-making asm routines).
OTOH it may make sense to re-use OS crypto API, which can be hardware-accelerated. VIA and Intel x86 CPUs have special opcodes, don't know about different ARM and DSP flavors

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL can be used on all three of those platforms.